# how to get the mentioned expected output from a object with nested objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have this data of objects ,
but unable to get expected output 
we need to iterate on object children and print the name values in a particular order as given below

expected output :

```
 kiran
    vish
     lav
     mall
```

tried code :

```js
let data = {
  name: 'kiran',
  children: [{
    name: 'vish',
    children: [{
        name: 'lav',
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'mall',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
}

/* kiran
    vish
     lav
     mall */

function indent(inputData) {

  function indentHandler(inpData, level, output) {
    if (!output) {
      let output = '';
    }
    if (inpData.children.length) {

      for (let i = 0; i < inpData.children.length; i++) {
        level = level + 1;
        console.log(addSpaces(level) + inpData.name + '\n');
        indentHandler(inpData.children[i], level);
      }

    } else {
      console.log(addSpaces(level) + inpData.name + '\n');
    }
    return output;
  }

  return indentHandler(inputData, 0, '');
}

function addSpaces(level) {
  let outp = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    outp = outp + ' ';
  }
  return outp;
}

indent(data)
```

https://jsbin.com/yanogok/edit?js,console

please correct my program as I m unable to get correct output

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yanogok/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your parent `console.log` out of loop
2. Do not change `level` in loop, just pass `level + 1`

```js
let data = {
  name: 'kiran',
  children: [{
    name: 'vish',
    children: [{
        name: 'lav',
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'mall',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
}

/* kiran
    vish
     lav
     mall */

function indent(inputData) {

  function indentHandler(inpData, level, output) {
    if (!output) {
      let output = '';
    }
    if (inpData.children.length) {
        console.log(addSpaces(level) + inpData.name + '\n');

      for (let i = 0; i < inpData.children.length; i++) {
        indentHandler(inpData.children[i], level + 1);
      }

    } else {
      console.log(addSpaces(level) + inpData.name + '\n');
    }
    return output;
  }

  return indentHandler(inputData, 0, '');
}

function addSpaces(level) {
  let outp = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    outp = outp + ' ';
  }
  return outp;
}

indent(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function indent(data){
    output = '';
    return (function indentHandler(data, level){
        output += addSpaces(level) + data['name'] + '\n';
        if (data['children'].length === 0){
            return output;
        }
        level += 1;
        data['children'].forEach(function(child){
            return indentHandler(child, level);
        });
        return output;
    })(data, 0, '');
}

function addSpaces(level) {
  let outp = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    outp = outp + ' ';
  }
  return outp;
}

indent(data)
```